# Search one a one object value into another object and compare with single value that will return boolean value

Tags: javascript

```
var A = {
  ENGLISH_US: "en-US"
}
var B = [
  { displayName: "English (India)", key: "en-IN" },
  { displayName: "English (Ireland)", key: "en-IE"}
]
var C = en-US
```

Search A object value into B object and compare with C that has to return an only boolean value

Comment: Hi Kristian! Do you want to search by value (if string "en-US" is among values of B object)?

Comment: yes, I want to search it by value. "en-US"

Comment: Ok, so you are taking value of A which is en-US, find if some inner object in B have some key with the very same value, and then compare it with C which is again en-US.
So you are basically comparing A to C. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: yeah, you are right

Comment: Please the solution in javascript only with a minimum number of steps.

Comment: One question - are you sure B is an Object? It looks like an Array now.
With Object you should have {key:value} pairs like
    
let B = {
      first: { displayName: "English (India)", key: "en-IN" },
      second: { displayName: "English (Ireland)", key: "en-IE"}
}

Comment: My bad its array of object.

Answer (score 0):

Still I'm not sure what is the intended functionality you are looking for, but for the first part you might consider using something like:

```
arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey)));
```